# How to solve the truncated nuclear norm minimization problem to global optima?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, non-convex-optimization, regularization, nuclear-norm

> **Definition**: Given a matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and a positive integer $r<\min\{m,n\}$, the truncated nuclear norm $\|X\|_{r,*}$ is defined as the sum of $\min\{m,n\}-r$ minimum singular values, that is, $\|X\|_{r,*}=\sum_{i=r+1}^{\min\{m,n\}}\sigma_{i}(X)$ where $\sigma_{i}(X)$ is the $i$th singular value of $X$. ([Hu et al., 2013](https://doi.org/10.1109/TPAMI.2012.271))

Let $X$ and $Z$ be $m\times n$ matrices. I am trying to solve the following optimization problem:

\begin{equation}
\hat{X}=\operatorname{arg}\min_{X}~~\alpha\|X\|_{r,*}+\frac{1}{2}\beta\|X-Z\|_{F}^{2}
\end{equation}
where $\|\cdot\|_{F}$ denotes the Frobenius norm.

I know this problem is *nonconvex*, but is it possible to get the global optimal solution? If yes, how? Thanks in advance for your help in any way.

Comment: You seem to be taking the singular values to be indexed in increasing order, contrary to the usual convention.

Comment: If you’re looking around for a paper about this, it might help to know that the truncated nuclear norm is sometimes called a “Ky Fan norm”.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion is appreciated. The singular values here are sorted as $\sigma_{1} \geq \sigma_{2} \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_{\min \{m, n\}} \geq 0$.

Comment: Whoops my mistake! Everything makes sense now; so the Ky Fan norm is not what you’re looking for

Comment: Anyway, thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful to characterize the truncated norm as $$\min\{\operatorname{trace}(U^TXU) : U^TU = I_{p\times p} \}$$ where $p = \min\{m,n\} - r$

Comment: I understand your suggestion, but I don't know how can this help solve the optimization problem.